# Наибольшая цифра в введенном числе

Tags: delphi, php, vba, javascript

1 программа

```
program task_delphi;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
Windows;

var
n: integer;
MAX: integer;

begin

write('Введите целое ило и нажите клавишу "Enter": ');
readln(n);

MAX := 0;

while n <> 0 do
begin
if ((n mod 10) > MAX) then
MAX := (n mod 10);
n := n div 10;
end;

writeln('MAX= ', MAX);
setconsoletitle('Done! :)');
Readln;
end.
```

2 программа

```
<script>
cislo = prompt("Введите какое-то целое число: ", "54648575");
cis = cislo;
if (!cislo) {
alert("Число надо ввести, число...");
return;
}
max = 0;
document.write("Входное число: " + cislo + "<br />");
while (cislo != 0) {
if ((cislo % 10) > max)
max = (cislo % 10);
cislo = cislo / 10;
}
document.write("Максимальное число из " + cis + ": " + max.toString()[0]);
</script>
```

3 программа

```
<?php
$cislo = 54648575;
$cis = $cislo;
$max = 0;
echo "Входное число: $cislo <br />";
while ($cislo != 0) {
if (($cislo % 10) > $max)
$max = ($cislo % 10);
$cislo = $cislo / 10;
}
echo "Максимальное число из $cis: <strong>$max</strong>";
?>
```

4 программа

```
Sub qq()
Dim cislo
Dim cis
Dim max As Integer
cislo = 438572
cis = cislo
max = 0
Do While (cislo <> 0)
If (cislo Mod 10) > max Then
max = cislo Mod 10
End If
cislo = cislo \ 10
Loop
MsgBox "Iaeneiaeuiia ?enei ec " + CStr(cis) + ": " + CStr(max)
End Sub
```

Comment: Все приведенные программы делают одно и то же: находят наибольшую цифру в введенном числе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не хочу кидать сюда стены текста, поэтому все на pastebin.

- [1 программа (Delphi)](http://pastebin.com/5rUDGVeZ)
- [2 программа (JavaScript)](http://pastebin.com/MLfGm3eV)
- [3 программа (PHP)](http://pastebin.com/tdd3YqnX)
- [4 программа (VB)](http://pastebin.com/7RhHBQ16)